# How split list of tuples to tuple of lists?

Tags: list, split, erlang, tuples

I'm asked to split list of tuples to tuple that has 2 list, in the following way:

```
splitter ([{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}]). = {[1,3,5],[2,4,6]}
```

I've tried to write the following code:

```
splitter([]) -> {[],[]};
splitter(L) ->(map (fun ({A, _}) -> A end, L))|(map (fun ({_, B}) -> B end, L)).
```

And it does not compile, the error I am getting is: syntax error before: '|'

where is the problem?:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the outer curly braces. Also, replace the `|` by `,` as that's what's used to separate tuple members.

```
splitter([]) -> {[],[]};
splitter(L) -> {(map (fun ({A, _}) -> A end, L)),
                (map (fun ({_, B}) -> B end, L))
               }.
```

Answer (score 1):

Empty list clause is unnecessary. You can use list comprehensions as well.

```
splitter(L) -> {[ X || {X, _} <- L], [X || {_, X} <- L]}.
```

You can make universal one as well

```
splitter_n(L) ->
    list_to_tuple(transpose([tuple_to_list(X) || X <- L])).

transpose([]) -> [];
transpose([[]|_]) -> [];
transpose(L) ->
    [[hd(X) || X <- L] | transpose([tl(X) || X <- L])].
```

In work

```
1> c(splitter).
{ok,splitter}
2> splitter:splitter_n([{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}]).
{[1,3,5],[2,4,6]}
3> splitter:splitter_n([{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}]).
{[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]}
```